# Значение NULL в столбце "idact" отношения "act" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL, поле idact объявлено как serial

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

Есть таблицы Account, Act.
Поля idUser idAct в БД(PostgreSQL 13) являются типа serial, также каскадное удаление и редактирование.
Пользователь имеет некие данные, реализованные по типу один ко многим. При обновлении информации пользователя и занесения ее в базу данных при помощи Spring Data, выдает ошибку в таблице Act, в которой поле idSeller ссылается на первичный ключ таблицы Account.

**ОШИБКА: значение NULL в столбце "idact" отношения "act" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
Подробности: Ошибочная строка содержит (null, 10, 3, 2, 1, 2020-12-03)**

Хотя я никак не изменяю никаких данных в таблице Act, только в Account.

В модели User и Act пробовал id помечать как `@Column (name = "iduser", insertable = false)`
Не помогло.

Модель User:

```
package com.computerAccessoriesStore.models;

import com.computerAccessoriesStore.models.enums.Role;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "account",schema = "public", catalog = "ComputerAccessoriesStore")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column (name = "iduser")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Date created_at;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idproduct")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idact")
    private List<Act> acts = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idcomment")
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idcard")
    private List<CreditCard> creditCards = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

Модель Act:

```
package com.computerAccessoriesStore.models;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "act",schema = "public", catalog = "ComputerAccessoriesStore")
public class Act {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idact")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long count;

    private Date created_at;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idseller")
    private User seller;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idbuyer")
    private User buyer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idproduct")
    private Product product;

}
```

Часть скрипта SQL:

```
create table Account(
idUser SERIAL primary key,
first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
created_at DATE NOT NULL ,
role VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

create table act(
    idAct SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    count INT NOT NULL,
    idSeller INT NOT NULL,
    idBuyer INT NOT NULL,
    idProduct INT NOT NULL,
    created_at DATE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idSeller) REFERENCES Account(idUser) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
    FOREIGN KEY (idBuyer) REFERENCES Account(idUser) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
    FOREIGN KEY (idProduct) REFERENCES product(idProduct) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Сервис редактирования данных User:

```
package com.computerAccessoriesStore.service.impl;

import com.computerAccessoriesStore.models.User;
import com.computerAccessoriesStore.repository.UserRepository;
import com.computerAccessoriesStore.service.UserService;
import com.computerAccessoriesStore.transfer.UserDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void add(UserDTO dto){
        User user = User.builder()
                .created_at(dto.getCreated_at())
                .email(dto.getEmail())
                .firstName(dto.getFirstName())
                .lastName(dto.getLastName())
                .password(dto.getPassword())
                .role(dto.getRole())
                .username(dto.getUsername())
                .build();
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(UserDTO dto) {
        User user = User.builder()
                .id(dto.getId())
                .created_at(dto.getCreated_at())
                .email(dto.getEmail())
                .firstName(dto.getFirstName())
                .lastName(dto.getLastName())
                .password(dto.getPassword())
                .role(dto.getRole())
                .username(dto.getUsername())
                .build();
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Полный лог ошибки:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: значение NULL в столбце "idact" отношения "act" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
  Подробности: Ошибочная строка содержит (null, 10, 3, 2, 1, 2020-12-03).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.remove(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRemoveAction.execute(CollectionRemoveAction.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1356) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3233) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2401) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar:5.4.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.computerAccessoriesStore.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.edit(UserServiceImpl.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.computerAccessoriesStore.controller.admin.UserController.blockUser(UserController.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае, неправильная связка данных в сущности User. Имеет отношения OneToMany.

При редактировании пользователя, сохраняя в базу, пытаемся перезаписать список актов, в которых id null.

Удаление

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idproduct")
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idact")
private List<Act> acts = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idcomment")
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idcard")
private List<CreditCard> creditCards = new ArrayList<>();
```

решит ошибку